# I want to know differences between the two functions arranged from quick sort

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

## Question

The following `randomQuickSort1(target, left, right)` and `randomQuickSort2(target, left, right)` were created from a generic random quick sort.
I'm looking for an example array that takes a few seconds when I use `randomQuickSort1(target, left, right)`, while that takes a long time when I use `randomQuickSort2(target, left, right)`.
I know the difference in the amount of spatial computation between the two functions, but I don't know how/what makes a difference in the amount of time computed.

#### Prepared quick sort

`partition(target, left, right)` divides numbers larger than `pivot` to the left and smaller numbers than `pivot` to the right.
`randomQuickSort1(target, left, right)` sorts from the shortest left or right of the segment, while `randomQuickSort2(target, left, right)` sorts from the left side of the segment.

```
int partition_not_random(int* target, int left, int right) {
    // ****************** CHANGE ******************
    int random = right - 1;
    // ****************** CHANGE ******************    
    // Exchange target[right] and target[random].
    int tmp = target[right]; target[right] = target[random]; target[random] = tmp;
    int pivot = target[right];
    int i = left-1; // i scans the array from the left.
    int j = right;  // j scans the array from the right.
    for (;;) {
        // Move from the left until hitting a value no less than the pivot.
        for(i++; target[i] < pivot; i++){}
        // Move from the right until hitting a value no greater than the pivot.
        for(j--; pivot < target[j] && i < j; j--){}
        if (i >= j)  break;
        // Exchange target[i] and target[j].
        tmp = target[i];  target[i] = target[j];  target[j] = tmp;
    }
    // Exchange target[i] and target[right].
    tmp = target[i];  target[i] = target[right];  target[right] = tmp;
    return i;
}

void randomQuickSort1(int* target, int aLeft, int aRight) {
    int left = aLeft; int right = aRight;
    while (left < right) {
        int i = partition_not_random(target, left, right);
        if( i - left <= right - i ){ // The left interval is shorter.
            randomQuickSort1(target, left, i-1);
            left=i+1;
        }else{                       // The right interval is shorter.
            randomQuickSort1(target, i+1, right);
            right=i-1;
        }
    }
}
void randomQuickSort2(int* target, int aLeft, int right) {
    int left = aLeft;
    while (left < right) {
        int i = partition(target, left, right);
        randomQuickSort2(target, left, i-1);
        left = i+1;
    }
}
```

#### General random quick sort

```
int partition(int* target, int left, int right) {
    // Select a number between left and right at random.
    int random = left + rand() % (right - left + 1);
    // Exchange target[right] and target[random].
    int tmp = target[right]; target[right] = target[random]; target[random] = tmp;
    int pivot = target[right];
    int i = left-1; // i scans the array from the left.
    int j = right;  // j scans the array from the right.
    for (;;) {
        // Move from the left until hitting a value no less than the pivot.
        for(i++; target[i] < pivot; i++){}
        // Move from the right until hitting a value no greater than the pivot.
        for(j--; pivot < target[j] && i < j; j--){}
        if (i >= j)  break;
        // Exchange target[i] and target[j].
        tmp = target[i];  target[i] = target[j];  target[j] = tmp;
    }
    // Exchange target[i] and target[right].
    tmp = target[i];  target[i] = target[right];  target[right] = tmp;
    return i;
}

void randomQuickSort(int* target, int left, int right ) {
    if (left < right) {
        int i = partition(target, left, right); // i: Position of the pivot.
        randomQuickSort1(target, left, i - 1);
        randomQuickSort1(target, i + 1, right);
    }
}
```

## What I tried

I tried ascending sorted arrays and descending sorted arrays, but there was no difference in execution time between the two functions.

Comment: Please edit your question. You have posted too much code. As far as I can see, you want to compare two quicksorts that differ only in how the pivot is chosen: The first one always picks the rightmost element, the second one chooses a random element. If that is so, make that clear, and remove the definitions and calls to `randomQuickSort[13]`, whch aren't used anywhere. Please make an effort to not to make answering your question harder than it needs to be.

Comment: For what it's worth: When you have monotonic arrays, the execution time should be much shorter for the randomly chosen pivot. If you pick one of the extreme elements in an already sorted array, your algorithm will degrade to the quadratic worst case. If you don't see any significant difference in execution, there might be an error in how you time your algorithm.

Comment: You do notice that `randomQuickSort` calls `randomQuickSort1`, rather than calling itself recursively?